# copy std::map<int, vector<int>> to std::map<std:string, vector<int>>

Tags: c++

Can we copy contents one one map to another map with different type of key?
`copy std::map<int, vector<int>> to std::map<std:string, vector<int>>`

Comment: How do you want to transform the keys?

Comment: This is just the reverse of your other question. The answer posted works almost exactly the same.

Comment: There are good hints at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281111)

Comment: Yes, but my previous question was deleted before i could finish reading it.

Comment: @Angel, Here: http://pastebin.com/gXuUVGgD

Answer (score 3):

You can't copy them. While the maps are instantiated from the same class template, they're still unrelated types, much like `struct Foo {};` and `struct Bar {};`

You can [`transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) one to the other, though:

```
std::map<int, std::vector<int>> m1;
std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>> m2;

std::transform(m1.begin(), m1.end(), std::inserter(m2, m2.end()),
    [](const std::pair<int, std::vector<int>>& p)
    {
        return std::make_pair(std::to_string(p.first), p.second);
    });
```

Comment: I get Error: to_string not a member of std

Comment: @Angel If you included `<string>` and the error is still there, it means your version of standard library doesn't have this function yet (it's relatively new to the C++ standard). Do some research on how to convert an int to string pre C++11.

Answer (score 1):

Respectfully stolen from @Ceasars deleted answer [the last time this was asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281111)...

1. Create an `std::map<std::string, vector<int>>`
2. Iterate through the old map
3. Change the key to be a std::string
4. Insert to the new map

Step 3 can be done with `boost::lexical_cast`, `std::to_string` (in C++11), or the nonstandard `itoa`.

Comment: I used Itoa I get this error  error: itoa was not declared in this scope

Comment: And then I tried using std::string = std::to_string(m1->first), I get Error: to_string not a member of std

Comment: I am getting error in step 4, `std::string key = std::to_string(m1->first) , after this i m doing m2.insert(key, m1->second)` But I get error saying no matching function for call to

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you just need to convert the int to a string. I would suggest something like this:

```
string newKey(itoa(key));
```

(Check that that works first :) )

Comment: `itoa` is non-standard. Try `std::to_string`.

Comment: @chris yep! that sounds better.